# Spring-Boot create bean with out name will cause "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, No qualifying bean of type[]found for dependency "

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-bean

I Create the bean by configuration with out name

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql")
public class DbConfiguration extends BaseDbConfiguration {

  @Bean//(name = "fix")
  @Override
  public DbClient createClient() {
      return super.createClient();
  }

}
```

usage:

```
@Autowired
private DbClient dbClient;
```

when I running application it can't start up

And throw NoSuchBeanDefinitionException：

No qualifying bean of type [DbClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

But I fix it by add name, why??

```
@Bean(name = "fix")
```

I also add a test such like this:

```
public class TestCreate {

    @NotNull
    private int test;

    public Test createTest() {
        return new Test(this.test);
    }

}
```

it configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestConfiguration extends TestCreate {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Test createTest() {
        return super.createTest();
    }

}
```

And autowired like this:

```
@Autowired
private Test test;
```

However, this test may work well

It also create Bean without name and Autowired with out Qualifier

Please Tell me why....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.

I have found the results:

Overriding bean definition for bean 'createClient': replacing ...

So Spring-Boot will create Bean by FunctionName rather than returning ObjectName.